# Why is select(2) called "synchronous" multiplexing?

Tags: c, node.js, asynchronous, posix, multiplexing

I am a bit confused at the moment about [select(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select), which states in the summary:

> select, pselect, FD_CLR, FD_ISSET, FD_SET, FD_ZERO - synchronous I/O
>   multiplexing

as far as I am aware many libraries and programs such as libuv and nodejs use select/epoll/kqueue/iocp for their event loop, which is used for their corresponding async/await feature (and async I/O?).

So, what exactly does synchronous multiplexing mean? Can I achieve async I/O using select? What exactly is the difference between **synchronous multiplexing** and **asynchronous multiplexing**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a parse error there. It is not synchronous multiplexing but multiplexing of synchronous I/O: `select` is used to multiplex synchronous I/O calls. `read` and `write` and such are called synchronous I/O because they will either block until the transfer is complete, or not do the transfer (non-blocking non-ready sockets for example).

This can be contrasted with truly asynchronous calls where the system call just initiates the transfer and it is completed in the background and a notification is given after the completion.

The nodejs and libuv are different beasts. Even though the I/O in C is possibly multiplexed and synchronous, it will appear as asynchronous to *them* - there is no blocking synchronous read calls because it all happens transparently on the C/library side.

Comment: Thank you! That really solved my confusion. How does select work internally though? I imagine it must either poll the status of the file descriptors or be notified asynchronously in order to unblock?

Comment: @Julius that is kernel magic, but it would very likely be asynchronous in there.

Answer (score 1):

> So, what exactly does synchronous multiplexing mean?

Synchronous operations are distinguished from asynchronous ones in that the former do not allow the caller to continue until they complete, whereas the latter do.  *Software* (a)synchronicity is closely related to multithreading, and the main characteristic of `select()` that makes its operation synchronous instead of asynchronous is that it works entirely within a single (user) thread of execution.  When you call `select()` your thread blocks until either one of the file descriptors you specified becomes ready, or the timeout you specified expires.

The alternative would be a programming model where you register interest in I/O on the file descriptors, then come back later to check whether they are ready.

It should be noted, however, that although `select()` is certainly synchronous itself, the multiplexing is mostly up to the programmer.  `select()` provides a means to achieve it, but performs no I/O itself.  It's essential brilliance is in giving you the information you need to avoid blocking trying to do I/O on one file descriptor while a different one is ready to be serviced.

> Can I achieve async I/O using select?

No, `select` doesn't do anything to particularly facilitate asynchronous I/O.  It helps you handle multiple I/O channels efficiently via a single thread, but that thread operates synchronously.  This nevertheless tends to be a big win, because I/O is very slow, and that slowness is mostly associated with I/O peripherals and media, not CPU and memory.  Generally speaking, a single thread has plenty of processing power to handle multiple I/O channels as long as it chooses wisely which ones to handle at any given opportunity, and `select()` facilitates that.